# Corner Ribbon in Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pfy3gv1/1/)

Im trying to make a corner ribbon for a responsive layout.

I've used the following to position it:

```
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: -100px;
```

I have the ribbon in place, my issue occurs when the user resizes the screen, how can I always get it so that the ribbon sites in the corner? i've tried playing around with different percentage offsets but it's hit and miss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't use width:100% for your ribbon

***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pfy3gv1/4/)***

```
.ribbon{
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    text-align: center;
    top: 10px;
    left: -75px;        /* !!! */
    width:200px;        /* !!! */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. Just another quick question - any tips on how to make the ribbon a bit smaller on smaller screens - this is why I originally declared width as a percentage, so it would get a bit smaller on smaller screens.

Comment: @panthro as Leo said, target a desired Media using the CSS's media queries and do whatever you need to. (P.S: to make it *smaller* all you need to do is to change the font size.)